# Spock: more details about error

Tags: groovy, spock, ratpack

We use ratpack framework for building REST server and spock for testing.

I need to tune spock output when condition unsatisfied (eg. stacktrace or response dump)

For example, following test:

```
def "Vk: Auth mr. John"() {
    when:
    request.param "vkId", vkId
    request.param "vkToken", vkToken
    request.port 5050 
    def resp = request.post "/auth/vk"

    then:
    resp.statusCode() == 200
    def json = resp.jsonPath()

    with(json) {
        response != null
        response.token != null
        response.userId != null
    }
}
```

Produces following error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

resp.statusCode() == 200
|    |            |
|    500          false
com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@10b033e
```

How can I make spock to provide more details such as response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you have to do something like:

```
assert resp.statusCode == 200,
       "resp.statusCode == $resp.statusCode (not 200) $resp.body"
```

Comment: Another option is to include `resp.body` in the assertion.

Comment: Thank you, great hint. But once I get result ```assert resp.statusCode() == 200, "not 200 ${resp.body().print()}"``` I get ```IOException: Attempted read on closed stream``` coz already read data in substituted string